# MySQL syntax (where==1)and(where=/=abc)

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I am sorry for the confusing question title. I don't know how to word it in a question. currently my statement is:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM accounts where isonline=1 and where!=clientid<>:clientid');
$stmt->bindParam(':clientid', $client);
$stmt->execute();
```

I am trying to receive all the data on the server for the people that are online that do not have the specific client code

Comment: The documentation on [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html), like a lot of the documentation for MySQL in general, is exceedingly specific on how the `SELECT` statement works. If you're having syntax errors that's the first place to look.

Answer (score 2):

You need to work on the where clause. It should only be used once...

```
where isonline = 1 AND clientid <> :clientid
```

Comment: Hello, I thank you for a response. I have tried your query and edited my clientcode down to pass easier. I am getting an error still.

#1054 - Unknown column 'andv025075' in 'where clause'